# Recover data from ransomware-encrypted databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm doing some work for an organization that was hit by the RYUK ransomware (a newer variant of HERMES), which has encrypted some large databases (around a half TB each). I don't know if backups are difficult to restore or simply don't exist; either way, I have been asked to do what I can with the encrypted files.

This ransomware doesn't appear to encrypt the entire `.mdf` file; it seems to only encrypt certain chunks.

Here's a snippet of the tail end of one of the databases as seen in a hex editor:

[image: hex editor snippet]

Do you know of any tools or methods by which I can extract any salvageable data? Potentially even resorting to options like reverse-engineering the storage format and writing a one-off utility. (I can get the table schema.)

Comment: What leads you to believe that the file is only partially encrypted?

Comment: `Potentially even resorting to options like reverse-engineering the storage format and writing a one-off utility.` That's a non-starter. The only true way to get out of this is via backups, if they don't have any then you'll have to either reverse the randomware technique using the correct key on the correct portions of the database or restore a backup. Those are your feasible options. YMMV on dumping out data depending on what parts of the database, if not all, are encrypted. If you can't read the schema data then it's going to be hard to know where datatypes start and end, let alone off-row.

Comment: @DougDeden I'm able to see strings like `%PDF-1.2`, so clearly not everything is encrypted. The `.mdf` files also all have modified timestamps close to one another, further suggesting a partial encryption. It would benefit an attacker to spend as little time as possible on each file to maximize damage.

Comment: @SeanGallardy Partial data loss is a fact of this situation. I just want to recover whatever can be recovered. I have the schema available from source control and a partial backup.

Comment: @Taudris  I'm not arguing, but the logical schema is different from the physical layout and linkages used by the storage engine. If the header or higher parts of the files are encrypted. Are they using columnstore or page compression which requires dictionary entries which may or may not be overwritten, etc. You can try 3rd party database readers but as I stated, YMMV. That's your best bet right now and chances are if you're able to get any data it's still going to be a huge loss. Worth a shot though.

Comment: I had to cope with a similar situation, i.e. partially encrypted MDF by ransom ware. I found some tools: https://www.systoolsgroup.com/sql-recovery.html, https://www.sysinfotools.com/mdf-recovery-pro.php, https://www.diskinternals.com/mssql-recovery/, https://www.kerneldatarecovery.com/sql-recovery.html. I tried to restore the MDFs with the demo versions they did indeed recover something. At the end of the day the customer's backup luckily wasn't encrypted too, as we first feared, so I didn't go further into the recovery of the MDFs. But you may want to try if it can help you.